# UIButton only detects touches on top half

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, touches

I am adding 3 UIButtons to a UIView, and usually only 1 to 2 of them will detect touches, and even then it will only be the top half of the buttons the detect them. Anyone know why this would happen?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        int randIndex = arc4random() % [images count];
      //  UIImage *randImage = [images objectAtIndex:randIndex];
        NSString *number = [numbers objectAtIndex:randIndex];
        [images removeObjectAtIndex:randIndex];
        [numbers removeObjectAtIndex:randIndex];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      //  [button setImage:randImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 8, 108, 40);
        button.tag = [number integerValue];
        for (UIView *sub in [baseone subviews]) {
            CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(sub.frame.origin.x + sub.frame.size.width, sub.frame.origin.y);
            button.frame = CGRectMake(topRight.x, 8, 108, 40);
        }
        [baseone addSubview:button];
    }
```

Comment: Something is on top of them.  Sometimes, with really complex layouts, you have to write code to search the view and find out what's overlaying what.

Comment: Nope, they dont overlap each other, and nothing else is on that uiview except the three buttons

Comment: So you think.  Are you sure the buttons fall entirely within their superview?

Comment: I've run into this problem when the button frame is left over from the wrong orientation. Make sure that your UI is designed to handle autorotation properly.

Comment: Hot Likes: Yep, 100% sure.

Comment: Luke: The app is locked from rotating, so it really shouldnt be a problem right?

Comment: As thelaws suggests, change "TouchUpOutside" to "TouchUpInside".

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that `baseone`'s width is only large enough to contain the first two buttons. Do you see the touch down selection of the third button?

Also, your control event is `TouchUpOutside`, I've usually seen `TouchUpInside`, was that intentional?

PS Doesn't solve your problem, but this loop:

```
for (UIView *sub in [baseone subviews]) {
       CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(sub.frame.origin.x + sub.frame.size.width,    sub.frame.origin.y);
       button.frame = CGRectMake(topRight.x, 8, 108, 40);
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
UIView * sub = [[baseone subviews] lastObject]
button.frame = CGRectMake(sub.frame.origin.x+sub.frame.size.width, 8, 108, 40);
```

since the last subview always determines the frame of the next button.

Comment: Youre right with that loop, I was overthinking it. And I was just seeing if it would detect other types of controlevents. Its not always the first 2 buttons that detect touches, its usually the middle one that doesnt work at all

Comment: Yeah, I've never played with "TouchUpOutside", but I don't think it's right.

Comment: I have seen cases where subviews bounds exceed the bounds of the parent. That causes this problem (like this answer describes). https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa2013/qa1812.html

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your buttons are overlapping each other or there could be overlapping views.

I would also take a look at this line here:

```
CGPoint topRight = CGPointMake(sub.frame.origin.x + sub.frame.size.width, sub.frame.origin.y);
```

I would suggest logging the CGPoint Value to make sure the button location is correct:

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(topRight));
```

Comment: Nope, they dont overlap each other at all